# Display html and css using http.get

Tags: css, angular, rxjs

I am trying to make a iframe like solution where i am making a http.get call and getting the site as a object containing html and css. The problem is that that i am using `<link>` tags since i get  the css path to a external source. And this causes the html to be loaded before all css is applied.

I thought the `link.onload = () => { sub$.next(); sub$.complete() }` would solve my problem but there is still issues loading them in the correct order.

```
Html$ = this._idToGetUrl.pipe(
    filter(id=> id!= null),
    switchMap(id => {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl(id))
            .pipe(
                switchMap(x => this.setLinkTags(x.css)
                    .pipe(map(_ => x.html))
                ),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    })
)

private setLinkTags = (css: CSS[]) => {
    const check = css.map((css, i) => {
        const sub$ = new Subject()
        if (document.querySelector(`[href="${css.path}"]`)) {
            sub$.next()
            sub$.complete()
            return sub$
        }
        const link = document.createElement('link')
        link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        link.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        link.onload = () => { sub$.next(); sub$.complete() }
        link.onerror = () => { sub$.next(); sub$.complete() }
        link.setAttribute("href", css.path)
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link)
        return sub$
    })
    return zip(of(...check))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onload` won't work for validating availability of the css file. Try this approach here

```
var loadCSS = function(url, callback){
    var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.href = url;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onerror = function(){
            if(callback) callback(link);
        }
        img.src = url;
}
```

http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/

You can replace `callback()` with `subject.next()` and may also need to change your code a bit to support it.